# Pjax not working with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, pjax

I've tried to add Pjax to a PHP site because I'd like to dynamically load content using ajax and pushState and Pjax seemed to be the best option.

In my `site.js` file I have:

```
$(document).pjax('nav li a', '.wrap');
```

I've checked other answers and it seems that the JS isn't wrong and I was wondering if it was because I'm using PHP?

### Update

I've taken the jquery.pjax.js from the GitHub page although I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'
```

In the `<head>` I have:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.pjax.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  // pjax
  $('ul a').pjax('#main')
})
</script>
```

Comment: What is not working? Which error are you getting?

Comment: That's the thing, I don't get any errors, just a full page refresh.

Comment: Latest jQuery doesnt have a live() method anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery.live() was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9.

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Use an older jQuery version or change your code, or the libraries code to use .on()

It looks like the latest version of pjax addresses this issue as well. See https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#legacy-api

Comment: hmm, this is a bit weird since I don't see any live function in pjax source ?

Comment: Its been fixed in more recent versions. Or possibly another script somewhere on his page is using it.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doens't have anything to with Pjax, it's only frontend feature to handle xhr request. For a good example, you can try to look at this demo page : http://pjax.heroku.com/, view source code and learn from it :)

Comment: That's not entirely true. Your webserver needs to recognize a pjax request and only send the content container, not the entire page.